# Why am I able to use the column_names property of a active record table model without the class prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails project, I have an active record model table Task. I needed to write a scope that I could pass a number of columns and the corresponding query would retrieve the table without those columns.

While searching for the best way (elegance and performance wise), I came across this code

```
scope :select_without, ->(*columns) do
  select(column_names - columns.map(&:to_s)) 
end
```

Now this is similar to the implementation I had in mind. I know calling `Task.column_names` returns an array of columns in the table.

But shouldn't calling `column_names` on its own return a nil class error ?

For some reason, the above code works. I pried and saw `column_names` in that scope returned the columns array too.

I feel I might be missing some basics. Could someone explain to me why `column_names` can be called without having to say `Task.column_names` ?

Thanks.

Comment: `scopes` are class methods (not instance methods) and so is `column_names`, so `self` is implied. It is the same reason you do not need to prefix the `select` method. If you were calling it from an instance method or externally you would need to include the class name

Comment: Oh.. so scope are class methods. I guess that explains it. Thanks.